# I am struggling to change imag src using attr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JQuery and I have a simple script that is not working and I can't figure why. I want to change a image by using the attr(). I have tried puting the script in the head section and it didn't work. I have placed both the images in the same root file but still it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Testing JQuery</title>
    


    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>

    <img src="20220801_021439_mfnr.jpg" 
      alt="my swollen feet" 
      heigth="500px" width="300px" 
      id="#myFeet">
     
    <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){
       
   $("#myPic").attr("src","IMG-20201105-WA0000.jpg");
      });

   </script>
    </body>
```

I have also tried other JQuery instructions using attr() , those instruction too dont work but everything else does.

Comment: You call it by id #myPic but your pic has id #myFeet.

Comment: Yes but also he but a `#` inside the id attribute. However the `#` is only used in js so jquerry understands the following string is a id. This is the same with classes they are put seperated by ` ` (space) but when writing a selector you put a `.` (dot) in front.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selectors `#myPic` and `id="#myFeet"` don't match. Also you don't put a `#` in front of the `id` in the `id` attribute. The `#` is only used in `css` and `js`.

```
id="#myPic"
```

Should just be

```
id="myPic"
```

Comment: Thanks and my apologies. The I'd are the same, I made an error when I posted this question. Initially i wanted to use an example but i decided to paste the actual code but forgot to change the "#myPic" I'd from the example. I just tried to remove the # from the id to $("myFeet"), still the picture doesn't  change.

Comment: You can have an example here https://codepen.io/vincentmenzel/pen/MWVPzed (The jquerry import is under settings). Also make sure the case matches.

Comment: @Vincet Menzel Thanks again for responding. The code does work. I copied your code into my editor it worked, while mine didn't. So I changed values of src from the one you have on your code to the picture I wanted to display in my code. It worked on ur code but still didn't work in mines. After some changes in my code, I changed location of the id attribute and placing it last in the img tag just as you did on your code, it worked fine. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: From   <img src="20220801_021439_mfnr.jpg" id="myFeet  height="500px" width="400px" > To <img src="20220801_021439_mfnr.jpg"                                           height="500px" width="400px" id="myFeet">

Answer (score 0):

ID must be same and id must be defined as id="myPic" not as id="#myPic" and id is wrong.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Testing JQuery</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>

    <img src="20220801_021439_mfnr.jpg" 
      alt="my swollen feet" 
      heigth="500px" width="300px" 
      id="myPic">
     
    <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){
       
   $("#myPic").attr("src","IMG-20201105-WA0000.jpg");
      });

   </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and my apologies. The I'd are the same, I made an error when I posted this question. Initially i wanted to use an example but i decided to paste the actual code but forgot to change the "#myPic" I'd from the example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to set attributes on given DOM element:

```
$('#id').attr('src', 'newImage.jpg');
```

to change the image source

In your case

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Testing JQuery</title>
    


    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>

    <img src="20220801_021439_mfnr.jpg" 
      alt="my swollen feet" 
      heigth="500px" width="300px" 
      id="myFeet">
     
    <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){
       
   $("#myFeet").attr("src","IMG-20201105-WA0000.jpg");
      });

   </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have just tried it out and it still doesn't change the initial picture.

Comment: it works - https://jsfiddle.net/uh4cw53p/   Also jquery id and html img id must be the same - myFeet

Comment: thanks again for responding. Please read my response to Vincent Menzel comment. Your suggestions really assisted me. Thanks for the help!!!!